# MinGW cc1plus.exe and collect2.exe "can't start the application correctly (0xc0210000). click OK to close the application"

Tags: c++, mingw, msys2

I recently installed MinGW64 through MSYS2 and I added it to path to test it in cmd, I created a simple .cpp script and tried to compile it with the `g++ 1.cpp -o 1.exe` command, but I get 2 error windows:

[image]

[image]

I tried using other commands too, like c++ instead of g++, but I get the same result, this is the code I'm trying to compile:

```
using namespace std;

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  cout << "something";
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Contrary to what you said, this looks like a runtime error. That would mean you have no actual **compilation** problem. Try swapping the `using namespace std` and `#include <iostream>` lines.

Comment: I got the same result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution, the reason why I was getting those errors was that I was using bitlocker on one of my drives, it didn't even contain files that were being used by the compiler (the program and mingw where all in a different drive) but removing bitlocker on my drive solved the problem